# <te form> + っと (conditional particle)

Tags: て-form, contractions, particle-と

> こんなとこで寝てっと風邪ひくぞ

Is this a contraction of something? How does it differ from something like 寝ると or 寝てると?

[image: naruto 21]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is obviously a contraction of 寝てると. Not sure if this pertains to certain dialects/age groups etc. though. Haven't heard this one myself in real life.

Comment: i learned that らりるれろ often turns into ん but i guess sometimes it also turns into っ huh? i think i've seen it in other places too like 寝るから -> 寝っから possibly.

Comment: @ogicu8abruok Many "proper" modern japanese forms come from this process, 走りて -> 走って　etc.

Comment: The article on 促音便[そくおんびん] (4-4) here might be some help? http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF

Comment: So does the と act like から in this sentence?

Comment: The と treated here (in 寝ていると and in "勉強すると分かる=If you study, you'll understand") and から in "勉強したから合格した=I studied, so I passed" are both 接続助詞(conjunctive particles). http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E The meanings are a bit different, the と means 'if~' and the から means 'because~'.

Comment: と is like if/when but only the logical if/when. と cannot be used like the "if" in something like "if you finish that before me, then come help me". For that we use a -tara verb.

Answer (score 2):

The ーと in this sentence relates two parts as a consequence, but also gives an admonishment: I.e. this character is effectively saying: "You shouldn't sleep in such a place or you will catch a cold, you know!".

(Contrast this with ーば (as in こんなとこで寝れば...）which would just states the fact/opinion plainly: "if you sleep in such a place, you will catch a cold.")

The "tto" contraction used here is emphatic, or possibly male speech. Or both. It strengthens the statement, as if the character is saying, "you really shouldn't sleep here."

It is a phonetic feature of Japanese that changes toward stopped consonants are emphatic. For instance consider：

> やはり→やっぱり
>
> 「。。。」と →　「。。。」って
>
> とても →　とっても